# Problema para Cerrar un JFrame desde un Boton dentro de un JPanel

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas tardes,

Tal como dice el titulo, mi inconveniente es que realice 2 JPanel que luego los agregue en un JFrame.

El problema es que en un JPanel, tengo el botón que me debería cerrar o dejar invisible el JFrame, pero al colocar un evento sobre el botón, no me cierra dicho JFrame.

Intente pasar por parámetro al JFrame la clase del JPanel, pero no funciono.
Agradezco toda ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Tengo el siguiente JPanel:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego Este Panel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Ambos en el JFrame:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que el el botón finalizar me deje invisible el Frame, pero al estar en el JPanel, no lo realiza.

SOLUCIONADO Saque el boton del JPanel y lo puse directamente en el JFrame.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El handler que implemente es:

```
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Por favor incluye un [mcve] a tu pregunta.

Comment: dentro de los listeners el this, no es como si referenciaras al objeto padre, sino al licener como tal, con eso estás volviendo invisible tu listener o el botón, trata de meter eso en un método externo y luego entonces llama ese método, por ejemplo public void makeInvisible() {setVisible(false);} y luego este método métolo en el listener

Comment: Muchas Gracias Sr1871 por tu Rta, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SOLUCIONADO Saque el boton del JPanel y lo puse directamente en el JFrame.

Marcado en color amarillo.

Comment: Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad. Intenta mejorarla añadiendo algo más de detalle: ¿por qué eso solucionó tu problema? ¿cómo quedó el código al final?

Comment: Ya edite y mostre la pantalla como quedo.

Answer (score 0):

entiendo que pudiste solucionar de una manera determinada quitándole visibilidad al JFrame. Sin embargo habitualmente se utiliza el método dispose(); si no me falla la memoria para cerrar ventanas dentro de una misma aplicación y System.exit(0); para salir de la aplicación. Voy a dejar una pantalla como ejemplo del uso del método dispose();.

```
package Vista;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class Ventana_libreria extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

public JPanel panelsuperior, panelcentral, panelinferior;
public JButton botonatras, botonadelante, botonsalir;
public JTextArea textarealibreria;
public JLabel titulo;
public JScrollPane scroll;



public Ventana_libreria()
{


    panelsuperior= new JPanel();
    panelcentral= new JPanel();
    panelinferior= new JPanel();
        textarealibreria= new JTextArea(33,50);
            botonatras= new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/flechaverdeatras.png"));
            botonadelante= new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/flechaverde.png"));
            botonsalir= new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/eject.png"));
                titulo= new JLabel();
                scroll= new JScrollPane(textarealibreria);  // Acá creo el scroll
                scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);   //acá lo declaro sólo vertical

                this.setTitle("Librería de ayuda y orientación");

                this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    this.add(panelsuperior, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    panelsuperior.add(titulo);
                    titulo.setText("Datos a tener en cuenta:");

                    this.add(panelcentral, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                //  panelcentral.add(textarealibreria);     // Acá adhiero el JTextArea al centro, no sirve esta linea, se adhiere mediante el scrollpane
                    this.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);// Acá lo adhiero al lado oeste del borderlayout



                    textarealibreria.setEditable(false);

                    this.add(panelinferior, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    //panelinferior.add(botonatras);  //Por ahora van a estar desactivados
                //  panelinferior.add(botonadelante);   //Por ahora van a estar desactivados
                    panelinferior.add(botonsalir);


                    textarealibreria.setText("\nÁrea de soporte, debés tener en cuenta que: \n\n• Como todas las cosas existentes los aviones tienen peso y está ligados a las fuerza de gravedad.\n• Este avión tiene un alcance máximo de 1000 km sin repostar en el aire. \n• Su capacidad de carga entre combustible y armamento nunca puede ser mayor a 3000 kg\n• Para despegar 'sin carga' necesita mínimo unos 2000 metros de pista a velocidad mínima aprox 250 km/h.\n• No es efectivo en los duelos a corta distancia.\n• Carga como máx 6 misiles de media corta distancia AMRAAM.\n• Su techo máximo de vuelo son 30000 feet o 99900 metros.\n• Su tren de aterrizaje es extremadamente sensible al vient y/o golpes.\n• Su maniobrabilidad es buena pero su rango de giro nunca es mayor a 65 grados superando los 350 km/h.\n• Cuenta con medidas electromagnéticas o E.C.M , junto con Chaff y Flares o bengalas.\n• El ECM hoy en día es casi obsoleto, no sirve para missiles modernos a menos que esté a menos de 100 m del objetivo.\n• El rango de efectividad de éxito de un AMRAAM a x<100km y x>=1km es del 99%.\n• El rango de efectividad de un Sidewinder moderno es de x<10km y x>=500m es del 99%.\n• Apartir de los 30000 feet pierde sustentabilidad por la liviandad del aire y/o se congelan sus partes.\n• En algunos casos con la turbina apagada y dependiendo del angulo de caída puede planear largas distancias.\n• La cuenta correspondiente al recorrido planeando es= distancia_recorrida*segundos_hasta_la_pista. depende del grado.\n• Para refueling envuelo se necesitan almenos 300 litros de combustible con un consumo menor a 20litros/seg.\n• Los dos modelos más conocidos son el F-16C y F-16B ,el B con una maniobrabilidad 10º menor al C por la plaza extra.\n• Es absolutamente inefectivo ante operaciones contra buques o cruceros.\n• Es altamente reflectivo ante las ondas del radar y el vuelo bajo no sirve a menos que los radares tengan ángulo de 60º.\n• Apesar de su popularidad y su bajo costo, no a todas las naciones les conviene esta unidad por su poca autonomía.\n• Su competidor directo desde el lado URSS es el mig 29, superándolo sólo en tecnología pero con menos maniobravilidad.\n• Los Sidewinder son guiado por calor a muy corta o corta distancia.\n• Los AMRAAM son guiados por radar a corta-media-larga distancia.\n• El AIM-7 Sparrow es un missil de los años 70, hoy en día se evaden hasta con confeti.\n• El AIM-54 Phoenix sólo lo carga el F-14 por su peso, y es 100% efectivo sólo a distancias mayores a 200km.\n• Para que la turbina encienda por la chispa debe pasar por un tiempo de calentanmiento aprox de 5 a 10 min.\n• El corte del sistema de EPU retorna en el corte anexo del la chispa y el combustible.\n• El alcance máximo de su radar nunca supera los 320 km, ganando claridad mientras se baja la distancia análisis.\n• Su sistema de armas no funciona sin radar.\n• No está diseñados para aterrizar en portaviones ni distancias de pista menores a 3 km.\n• La vlocidad de despegue ideal sin carga es de 250 a 450 km/h.\n• La distancia de aterrizaje nunca puede ser menor a 3 km.\n\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \n\n• Este software está inspirado en el legendario simulador de vuelo Falcon 4.0 del año 1998 que hoy en día se sigue actualizando\n• Su secuela es el Falcon BMS el cual es un soft hijo nutrido por la comunidad Falcon BMS.\n• Este software no intenta ser copia de ningun otro y mantiene originalidad en su temática.\n• Este sofware fue diseñado por Axel Berlot, sin Netbeans ni otro gestor gráfico, sólo código puro en Eclipse IDE.");

                this.botonsalir.addActionListener(this);


}

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      Object obj=e.getSource();
      if(obj.equals(botonsalir))
      {
          this.dispose();
      }
  }


}
```

Esta pantalla es sólo una parte de un juego o applicacion que hice hace unos años, fijate que en  this.botonsalir.addActionListener(this); le estamos diciendo que le estamos asignando una acción al boton. y abajo le decimos que cierre la ventana si se presiona el botón con el método dispose(), osea le decimos this.dispose(); cerrar el JFrame de la clase actual.

Después de bastante tiempo usando swing, awt, entendí que tiene varios métodos interesantes que simplifican la existencia y que no son absolutamente necesarios pero funcionan y bien.

Hay que tener en cuenta que este metodo cierra un JFrame, no todo el programa como System.exit(0), y que se puede obtener un resultado similar con el metodo setVisible(true/false); sin embargo el dispose() es más indicado para cerrar un JFrame.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayuda berlot83, pero necesito tener la informacion del Frame que oculto y el dispose, la borraria. El exit saldria de la aplicacion, asi que solo me sirve el setVisible.